# Find coordinate of the shortened (elongated) line end

Tags: tikz-pgf

I draw elongated line

```
\draw[shorten >=-2] (0,1) -- (3,5);
```

and I need coordinate of the line end.  If I write

```
\draw[shorten >=-2] (0,1) -- (3,5) coordinate (a);
```

I simply get `(a) = (3,5)`

How to get the coordinate of the elongated line end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a *dimension* for shorten:

```
\draw[shorten >=-2pt] (0,1) -- (3,5);
```

Then you can use `calc` to find the same point with `($(3,5)!-2pt!(0,1)$)`. 
See:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw[thin, gray] (0,0) grid (5,5);    
    \draw[shorten >=-2pt] (0,1) -- (3,5);
    \path ($(3,5)!-2pt!(0,1)$) node [draw,circle] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is a zoom around `(3,5)`:

[image: Zoom around (3,5)]